# Unwanted Real number generated

Tags: database, ms-access

I have a weird problem if you can call it a problem that is.
Sorry in advance, the database is in french.

I have a table which hold the time a user passed on a specific task
I want to sum the time passed for every task

I'm able to get a sum from the database but the data is kind of wierd

The field is a real number to start with

Example, if I sum 0,35 + 0,63 + 1 I should get 1,98 Data without a sum:
[image: Data without a sum]
But instead Access give me 1,97999998927116 Data with sum:
[image: Data with sum]

If I was to sum only integer the number would be correct

I know I could simply use a round function to get rid of it.
But I would like to know why it does this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because Sum uses [floating-point arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating-point_arithmetic) if you execute it on a column that is defined as a `Single` or a `Double`

Floating-point arithmetic is often inaccurate.

You can avoid these kinds of errors by defining your column as a `Decimal` or as `Currency`